# Customizing main_menu so that it shows nested elements with styling in Drupal 7

Tags: routes, navigation

I have the following menu structure which i like to implement in Drupal 7 :

```
<ul id="dropdown-menu" class="fixed">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So far i have the base elements displaying correctly using :

```
<?php 
print theme('links__system_main_menu', 
array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'dropdown-menu', 
'class' => array('fixed')))); 
?>
```

Problems :

- It doesn't display nested elements
- I can only control the styling of the first level but in my code i have to apply a subclass of 'sub-menu' according to my theme.

Can someone point me to a starting point ? Thanks

Comment: Exactly in the same boat as you. Starting to annoy me, real bad. Unfortunately your question didnt get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it's not possible to make `theme('links__system_main_menu' [...])` display the nested elements. That suprised me, too...

One way to fix this: set up a region in the theme for the menu and put a menu block in there. This will display the nested elements, however styling the menu itself won't be much easier than before. `theme_menu_tree()` and `theme_menu_link()` hooks could be useful.

Also, check out the [Menu block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module.

p.s. I'm currently doing something similar that you do and it seems to be quite complicated for me, too, so I just summarized what I've already found.